# What is the order in this Union by Rank diagram?

Tags: algorithm, tree, disjoint-sets

I'm having trouble understanding the following diagram:

[image]

Why is A linked to D instead of B? Why is C linked to F instead of D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule for union by rank is to attach the smallest tree to the root of the largest tree.

At the first step `A` is united to `D` (this is *just an example* I guess - you could do any other way), so after `union(A, D)` you can have either `A_0 -> D_1` or `D_O -> A_1` since the 2 singleton trees have the same rank you pick one at random, in this case `D`, to be the root.